# function that cleans values passed through $_POST before it submits it

Tags: php, function, preg-replace

I'm writing a function that takes the content from `$_POST`, inserts it in a string and then returns the resulting string

To the question "What is your favorite color?" the user inputs `blue`
To the question "What is your favorite animal?" the user inputs `dog`

```
$content = "The visitor's favorite color is {color}";
$content = sentenceBuilder($content);

$content = "The visitor's favorite animal is a {animal}";
$content = sentenceBuilder($content);

function sentenceBuilder($content){
   global $_POST;
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
     if($key=='color'){
      $content = preg_replace("/\{($key+)\}/", $value, $content);
     }
     if($key=='animal'){
      $content = preg_replace("/\{($key+)\}/", $value, $content);
     }
    }
   return $content;
}
```

This returns "The visitor's favorite color is blue" and "The visitor's favorite animal is a dog." If they leave the color element blank, it returns "The visitor's favorite color is " and "The visitor's favorite animal is a dog". If they leave both elements blank, it returns 2 incomplete sentences.

So, I tried to modified it to say so that if `$value` was empty, the function would just skip it and move on to the next (as this uses every form element that moved over in the $_POST)...

```
if($key=='color' && $value!=''){
  $content = preg_replace("/\{($key+)\}/", $value, $content);
}else{
  $content ='';
}
if($key=='animal' && $value!=''){
  $content = preg_replace("/\{($key+)\}/", $value, $content);
}else{
  $content ='';
}
```

With this added, the result I get is blank. No sentences or anything. Even if they fill out the elements, the result is still blank with this code added.

So I tried this instead.

```
function sentenceBuilder($content){
   global $_POST;
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
     if(isset($value) && $value!=''){
       if($key=='color'){
        $content = preg_replace("/\{($key+)\}/", $value, $content);
       }
       if($key=='animal'){
        $content = preg_replace("/\{($key+)\}/", $value, $content);
       }
     else{
      $content = '';
     }
    }
   return $content;
}
```

This yielded the same results.

> TLDR;
>
> > I want to be able to have this function replace content with values that are not empty with a sentence. The ones that are empty, I would like for the content to be not displayed.

**UPDATE**

I got the code to work. Had to redesign it to make it happen though.

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST)){
$content = "The visitor's favorite color is {color}";
echo sentenceBuilder($content);
?> <br/> <?php
$content = "The visitor's favorite animal is a {animal} from {land}";
echo sentenceBuilder($content);
?> <br/> <?php
$content = "The visitor is from {land}";
echo sentenceBuilder($content);
?> <br/> <?php
$content = "The visitor is from Iowa";
echo sentenceBuilder($content);
?> <br/> <?php
$content = "The visitor is from {state}";
echo sentenceBuilder($content);
}

function sentenceBuilder($content){
     preg_match("/\{(.*?)\}/", $content, $checkbrackets);
     if(!empty($checkbrackets)){
         $gettext = str_replace('{', '', $checkbrackets[0]);
         $gettext = str_replace('}', '', $gettext);

         if(array_key_exists($gettext,$_POST)){
             if(!empty($_POST[$gettext])){
                $content = preg_replace("/\{($gettext+)\}/", $_POST[$gettext], $content);
             }else{
                $content = ''; 
             }
         }
     }
   return $content;
}   

?>


<form method="post" action"sentencebuilder.php">
<input type="text" name="color" />
<input type="text" name="animal" />
<input type="text" name="land" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Thanks for the help Guys. Enter it in and you'll see what I was going for. I am currently working on it to change additional brackets that exist within the question.

Comment: There is no "one function" for "cleaning" input. "cleaning" is context-sensitive. Sanitizing a string using an SQL-specific function is utterly pointless if the string is going to be used in an HTML context. And tip: $_POST and its cousins are superglobals. They're available in all scopes. `global $_POST` is useless/redundant.

Comment: Thank you for the tip.

I understand that the cleaning is context sensitive... that is what this function I wrote is... context based. It cleans the content for me. I was not asking for a function to clean content, but why this function I did write will not handle the empty values different as requested.

Comment: Plus, why the foreach loop? Why loop over the entire post array and check every key if a particular key exists? `if (isset($_POST[$key]) && ($_POST[$key] != '')) { ... }` would be far far more efficient.

Comment: the foreach loop is there because it handles everything that is passed through the $_POST... this snippet i gave is just one tiny part to try to make sense of things for people that may be able to help.

Can you answer why the info is not displaying, as per the request in the original post?

Comment: You're getting a blank when a color *is* present?

Comment: No Jay, if they leave the color input empty, the result is that it returns an incomplete sentence. The desired result is that if the color input is empty, then the the function returns no sentence at all.

Comment: so you want if color is empty then no output?

Comment: But you said *"With this added, the result I get is ALL blank."*, so I was a little confused.

Comment: Ahh sorry.

What I mean is that when I add the condition to see if the $value is blank, it returns nothing at all. INCLUDING for the other values that are getting passed through $_POST.

I'll edit the code to make it more sense.

Comment: Yes Rakesh, I would like for to output nothing if they left the input element empty. But only for the ones they left empty. I still need it to output the complete sentences for $values that are filled.

Comment: I edited the OP to try to help it make more sense.

Answer (score 3):

Use this code, definitely that's the solution of you problem:-

```
<?php
    $main_content = array();
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
     unset($_POST['submit']);
      $main_content['color'] = "The visitor's favorite color is {color}";
      $main_content['dog'] = "The visitor's favorite dog is {dog}";
      $main_content['school'] = "The visitor's favorite school is {school}"; 
      $formData = array_filter($_POST);
      if(!empty($formData)) {
        echo sentenceBuilder($formData, $main_content);
      }
    } 

    function sentenceBuilder($formData=null, $main_content=null){
            $newContent = "";
        foreach ($formData as $key => $value) {
            $newVal = "";   
            $newVal = preg_replace("/\{($key+)\}/", $value, $main_content[$key]);
            $newContent .= $newVal.". <br/>";   
        }

        return $newContent;
      }
    ?>


    <form method="post" action="#">
    <input type="text" name="color" placeholder="color" />
    <input type="text" name="dog" placeholder="dog" />
    <input type="text" name="school" placeholder="school" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />

**OUTPUT:**

    The visitor's favorite color is RED. 
    The visitor's favorite dog is BULLDOG. 
    The visitor's favorite school is CAMPUS SCHOOL.
```

Comment: Leaving one field blank returns this.

The visitor's favorite color is {color} 
The visitor's favorite animal is a dog.

I appreciate the help, but this only bypasses the ones with missing values. This is only half the problem. The goal is to keep it from displaying the sentence at all if the input was left blank.

Comment: Ok You edited the question. :) Let me repost the answer. I have a simple solution of you problem.

Comment: The visitor's favorite color is blue. 
The visitor's favorite dog is .... 
The visitor's favorite school is lakota. 

I left dog blank. This is the result.

what I would like to see when i leave the dog one blank is this.

The visitor's favorite color is blue. 
The visitor's favorite school is lakota.

Comment: Can you write the output what actually you are wishing for:- 1) The visitor's favourite color is Blue. The visitor's favourite dog is ... The visitor's favourite animal is dog. ----OR-- 2) The visitor's favourite color is Blue. The visitor's favourite animal is dog. WHICH ONE YOU NEED?

Comment: Okay i got you now. I am editing the answer again. Please check. And Dont forget to vote up if correct.

Comment: The output I want is that if $_Post[''] has no value in it it, then it takes the $content (the sentence) and eliminates it completely. This way it only displays sentences that have $values.

Comment: Ok Zach you just need to add the !empty condtion:- It checks for empty ness of a string. please check :)

Comment: I have tried that already. !empty is much like !='', I have tried them both with no luck =/

Comment: Did you execute the code on your server. Because this is working perfectly working in my computer system.

Comment: It will not include the sentence, having the field value as empty.

Comment: It is working, but it is not the same result.

This one produces the same sentence. Whereas the one that I am working with passes the sentence into the function, and the function determines the sentence to display based on the value of the $key. And then determines whether or not to actually display the sentence based on if the value of $value exists or not.

Comment: You need to change `$val` to `$value` in `$newContent .=`, otherwise good answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help you

```
<?php
$content = '';
echo $content = sentenceBuilder($content);

function sentenceBuilder($content){
   global $_POST;
   $content = "The visitor's favorite color is {key}";
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
     if (isset($_POST[$key]) && ($_POST[$key] != '')) {
      $content = preg_replace("/\{(key+)\}/", $value, $content);
     }
    }
   if(strpos($content, '{key}') !== false)
     return $content='';
   else
     return $content;
}?>

<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="color" />
<input type="text" name="gh" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

If you want first `color` check then try

```
if (isset($_POST['color']) && ($_POST['color'] != '')) {
   $content = preg_replace("/\{(key+)\}/", $value, $content);
}
elseif (isset($_POST[$key]) && ($_POST[$key] != '')) {
   $content = preg_replace("/\{(key+)\}/", $value, $content);
}
```

Comment: I had no luck with this one either.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you really need the **function** and not just 'inline' code. In that case, this function will do the trick (if I understand your wishes correctly).

In the comments of the code you will find some guidance.

Hope this helps :)

```
function sentenceBuilder($content = '')
{
    preg_match_all('/\{(.*?)\}/', $content, $matches); // Find all {...} matches
    $valueMissing = false; // If a POST value is missing, this will be set to TRUE

    if(isset($matches[0]) && !empty($matches[0])) { // Braces are found
        foreach($matches[0] as $id => $match) {
            // Note the usage of $matches[0] vs $matches[1]: $matches[0] = '{animal}','{land}',  while $matches[1] = 'animal','land' without the braces
            $key = (isset($matches[1][$id]) ? $matches[1][$id] : false); // Quick if/else
            $postValue = ($key != false ? (isset($_POST[$key]) ? $_POST[$key] : false) : false); // Quick if/else (double)
            if($postValue == false) {
                $valueMissing = true;
                break; // Leave the foreach loop
            } else {
                $content = str_replace($match, $postValue, $content); // Replace the value
            }
        }
        if($valueMissing) {
            return ''; // Return empty string (braces found, but not all values were found in the POST)
        }
    }
    return $content; // Return the content
}
```

*-------- ORIGINAL POST --------*

The preg-replace seems a bit overkill for this, **isset()** and **empty()** will do the trick.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST))
{
  // Start with empty content
  $content = '';

  // Only add content (.=) when the field is set (posted) and NOT empty
  if(isset($_POST['color']) && !empty($_POST['color'])) {
    $content .= "The visitor's favorite color is " .$_POST['color']. "<br/>";
  }
  if(isset($_POST['animal']) && isset($_POST['land']) && !empty($_POST['animal']) && !empty($_POST['land'])) {
    $content .= "The visitor's favorite animal is a " .$_POST['animal']. " from " .$_POST['land']. "<br/>";
  }
  if(isset($_POST['state']) && !empty($_POST['state'])) {
    $content .= "The visitor is from " .$_POST['state']. "<br/>";
  }
  if(isset($_POST['number']) && !empty($_POST['number'])) {
    $content .= "The visitor's favorite number is " .$_POST['number']. "<br/>";
  }

  // If there is some content, show it
  if(!empty($content))
  {
    echo $content;
  }
  else
  {
    echo "Please fill in some values!";
  }
}
else
{
  ?>

<form method="post" action"<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
  Favorite color: <input type="text" name="color" /><br />
  Favorite animal: <input type="text" name="animal" /><br />
  from land: <input type="text" name="land" /><br />
  <br />
  Favorite number: <select name="number">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="SEND this form" />
</form>

<?php }
```

And you can use HTMLPurifier (for example) to 'filter' any user-input data. http://htmlpurifier.org/

Comment: What you posted, while is useful for passing variables on submit, would not be useful for the function I am writing. Preg replace is exactly what the function needs to complete its task.

The code I posted to get help with was only a minor example for an issue I was having.

Thank you for your reply though. I do appreciate any input that may be beneficial!

Answer (score 0):

This works.

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST)){
$content = "The visitor's favorite color is {color}";
echo sentenceBuilder($content);
?> <br/> <?php
$content = "The visitor's favorite animal is a {animal} from {land}";
echo sentenceBuilder($content);
?> <br/> <?php
$content = "The visitor is from {land}";
echo sentenceBuilder($content);
?> <br/> <?php
$content = "The visitor is from Iowa";
echo sentenceBuilder($content);
?> <br/> <?php
$content = "The visitor is from {state}";
echo sentenceBuilder($content);
}

function sentenceBuilder($content){
 preg_match("/\{(.*?)\}/", $content, $checkbrackets);
 if(!empty($checkbrackets)){
     $gettext = str_replace('{', '', $checkbrackets[0]);
     $gettext = str_replace('}', '', $gettext);

     if(array_key_exists($gettext,$_POST)){
         if(!empty($_POST[$gettext])){
            $content = preg_replace("/\{($gettext+)\}/", $_POST[$gettext], $content);
         }else{
            $content = ''; 
         }
     }
 }
return $content;
}   

?>


<form method="post" action"sentencebuilder.php">
<input type="text" name="color" />
<input type="text" name="animal" />
<input type="text" name="land" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```